# Not able to see Procedure/Function body in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am not able to see Procedure/Function body in package view Oracle SQL Developer connected to Oracle 11g.. Any idea how can I see that

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like you're in the SPEC, use the toggle spec/body button in the toolbar, looks like a package, to the left of the gears

Comment: can u tell me the path to go there

Comment: look up, there is a toolbar above your code, hit the 4th icon/button

Comment: clicked on that..nothing happened ..it just got highlighted..attached the screenshot

Comment: that means your package doesn't have a body

Comment: not true..as I am able to see the same package with bodies in PL-SQL developer..attached above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199383/discussion-between-sromit-and-thatjeffsmith).

Comment: Thanx @thatjeffsmith, you correctly pointed out, I was logged in as diff user in both the tools. Once I changed the user I was able to see the package body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see the pacakge body if you press the plus (+) button you had right at the name of your pacakge.

[image: check_pkg_body]

If you don’t see it, two things may be happening, you don’t have the permissions (grants) on the user with which you are connected to the database session or the package body doesn’t exist.

To check if the package body exist you could export the definition,

[image: pkg_export]

You should also check if you are connected to the right environment

Comment: yeah..I was logged in as a different user in PL-SQL developer and SQL Developer..Once I logged in as user who had grants..I was able to view the package body..Thanx for pointing that out